# Cosine of a number with no math.h. Unknown error 1.#INF00

Tags: c, stdio, trigonometry

Well, I have a problems with a specific C code. I'm dealing with solving a task without using any "refined" coding, that is, doing regular stuff with the simplest of the libraries and functions. Particulary, I am ONLY allowed to use stdio.h , not any library more. And no strings, also.

The problem: I have to do the cosine of a real number x (stored in double), which is given by the user, using this expression: cos (x) = ((x^(2i))/((2i)!))*(-1)^i, all this inside a sumatore from i = 0 to i = n, being n the precision (an int number) which the user chooses.
Ok, I've managed to do this code so far:

```
        scanf("%lf", &x);
        r1 = x;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++){
            for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < 2*i; cont1++){
                r1 = r1*r1;
            }
            for(cont2 = 1; cont2 <= 2*i; cont2++){
                r2 = r2*cont2;
            }
            for(cont3 = 1; cont3 < i; cont3++){
                r3 = (-1)*(-1);
            }
            result = result + (r1/r2)*r3;
        }
        printf("The result is %lf\n", result);
```

But the output is always `1.#INF00`, all the time. Does anybody know why this happens? Could somebody tell me how to manage to get the right code? It would be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do `r3 = (-1)*(-1);`? It will always be the same no matter how much you loop.

Comment: Please show how are all the variables declared.

Comment: doing `r1 = r1*r1` 2i times isn't the same as r1^2i (if that's what you meant to do). Didn't you mean `r1 = r1*x`?

Comment: Yeah, I see what you say... I've corrected the r3 and r1 issue, thank you for the feedback. About the variables: - double result = 0, r1, r2 = 1, r3 = -1, x; - int i, n; I still haven't solved the problem, I think it is that the nested for loops aren't necessary in fact, as @chux suggests, or the main for loop could be eliminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect term calculation.
Term variables are not re-initialize each loop, which appears to be OP's algorithm's need.

[Edit]  Code

```
double MyCosine(double Angle, int Terms) {
  int cont1, cont2, cont3;
  double r1, r2, r3;
  // r1 = Angle;
  int i, n = Terms;
  double result = 0.0;
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    r1 = 1.0;
    for (cont1 = 0; cont1 < 2 * i; cont1++) {
      // r1 = r1 * r1;
      r1 = r1 * Angle;
    }
    r2 = 1.0;
    for (cont2 = 1; cont2 <= 2 * i; cont2++) {
      r2 = r2 * cont2;
    }
    r3 = 1;
    // for (cont3 = 1; cont3 < i; cont3++) {
    for (cont3 = 0; cont3 < i; cont3++) {
      // r3 = (-1) * (-1);
      r3 = r3 * (-1);
    }
    result = result + (r1 / r2) * r3;
  }
  printf("%e %e\n", result, cos(Angle));
  return result;
}
```

A re-write would not need to re-initialize the term and then the nested `for` loops could be eliminated.  Other simplification exists.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried the code, though, and it gives me stranges results, which are not the cosine of the number. About the nested for loops, I think I see what you say. Either I eliminate the inside fors or I take out the main one, because if not I'm just doing the complete sumatore of each term in one loop and then loop it again on the main one. I'm trying to solve it eliminating the nested ones, but still no success.

Comment: For future reference, do not say "it gives me stranges results", instead provide more useful info like "x=0.1, n= 5 gave me 0.123 and 0.995 expected". The `cont3 `for()` loop should start at 1.  re-did `r3` calc.  Re-did `r1` calculation.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much, now I see what was wrong, besides not reinitzialiting the variables every loop. I'm sorry for not being very specific, this is my first post here and I'm not very aware of the most useful info. So thank you again, I'll take good note of your advices.

Comment: @user2826951 Welcome to SO.  Suggest up-voting all the posts you found useful and after a time (hours, days), accept one that met your need.

Answer (score 0):

When you compute the terms `x^(2i) / (2i)!`, you **can't** compute `x^(2i)` and `(2i)!` separately and then divide, as both of them will grow larger than the largest number that fits in a `double` very quickly. Therefore you are running into `inf`s and similar problems.

You need to find a clever more robust way to calculate these terms (which is probably the point of this assignment).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Hmm, after searching for the 1.#INF00 issue, before posting here, it said that could be the problem, but after re-reading my code it didn't seem to have divisions by 0 or such things, which were the most probable possibility, so I thought it had to do with something else. I'll check again for those issues when I try to find a way to code it better.